# Unable to get subscribe data and assigning value to variable angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am facing a strange problem , the same code I have written in several modules are working fine. I am trying to get value from HTTP service, after subscribing I got an object but if I try to assign this value to an instance of interface it shows the object is undefined.

```
saleInvoice:sInvoice;// this one is working fine...
tempCusRat:customerRates;

this.service.getCustRatebyProd(custId,prodId)
.subscribe(item => {
  
    this.tempCusRat = item;
    console.log("custome sale price:" + this.tempCusRat.rate);

  }
)
```

console: ERROR TypeError: this.tempCusRat is undefined

however, if I check the value of the item it shows the same error. I also tried to check the item in the console it shows [Object object]

Comment: Show us all of your code please. Your example isn't enough.

Comment: If you are saying that item is [Object object] then the problem must be with your endpoint response. Try to access item(response) first then assign it to any instance. I would suggest you to show your whole code.

Comment: you are using arrow function and "this" keyword means the class which you are using this code , are you sure you declared tempCusRat  in that class?

Comment: i find problem ... data was loaded in array from .net web api . and i was expecting single object. i just make changes in api and problem solved ... thanks for everyone.